# Show custom properties in pose mode

Tags: rigging, drivers

I want to use a custom property on a bone as a driver. Can I get it to show up in the 'n' menu in pose mode, or is that just for object mode?

[image]

Comment: Properties on bones show up in the mode they were added to.  If you want custom properties to show up in pose mode, add them in pose mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Try this.]

Create your custom properties in the bone tab. The property automatically will appear when you select this bone in pose mode.